Implementing Filtering in Spring Boot Backend
I'm encountering an issue with applying a filter to a table in the backend using Java Spring Boot. I'm receiving a list of games with various attributes including mechanisms.
{
  "id_game": 1,
  "code": "DR54HY",
  "name": "Name",
  "age": 4,
  "price": 29,
  "description": "Description",
  "nbGamer": 2,
  "mechanisms": [
     {
       "id_mechanism": 1,
       "name": "Card"
     },
     {
       "id_mechanism": 2,
       "name": "Adventure"
     }
  ], 
}, //etc

I'm trying to implement a filter to retrieve games based on specific mechanisms name. However, the current implementation is not working as expected. When I try to retrieve games based on multiple mechanisms, it doesn't filter the games properly. Here's the code:
GameRepository.java:
@Repository
  public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Integer> {
    Page<Game> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Game> findAllByMechanismsName(Pageable pageable, List<String> mechanismsName);
}

GameService.java:
 @Service
    public class GameService {
        
        @Autowired
        private GameRepository gameRepository;
        
        public Page<Game> getGames(Pageable pageable, List<String> mechanismsName) {
            
            if (mechanismsName != null) {
                return gameRepository.findAllByMechanismsName(pageable, mechanismsName);
             } else {
                return gameRepository.findAll(pageable);
            }
   }

GameController.java:
@RestController
public class GameController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;
    
    @GetMapping("/games")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Game>> getGames(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int pageSize,
            @RequestParam(required = false) List<String> mechanismsName
            
    ) {
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);
        Page<Game> gamesPage = gameService.getGames(pageable, mechanismsName);
        
        if (gamesPage.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(gamesPage, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

Here's the Postman request:

GET /games?page=0&pageSize=10&mechanismsName=Card

or

GET /games?page=0&pageSize=10&mechanismsName=Card,Power


Shouldn't it be findAllByMechanisms_Name? Also, could you share your Game entity in the question with relevant code.

First your arguments are wrong, afaik the Pageable needs to be last, second y our methodname is wrong it should be findAllByMechanismsNameIn as you are passing a collection. Tip you can just use the PageRequest or Pageable as a controller method argument, no need to create that yourself.
